# Angular Dart to JavaScript result way too big for production?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, size, dart, dart2js

Is it right that the minimum / smallest compiled and minified JavaScript size of an AngularDart application (that does nothing) is about 650KB ?

That is way too much for mobile applications and even too big for normal applications.

Does anybody know how to get it under 100KB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "smallest compiled and minified Javascript" is 190KB today.  We are tracking that number and care about deploy size and performance.

If you are seeing 650KB, there may be a bug somewhere; if you could provide details in an issue at https://github.com/angular/angular.dart we would be grateful.

Also, if you could share your use-cases and requirements it would help us in designing the system.  e.g. we would love to understand the 100KB requirement.

Comment: Thank you James. It is very important to our customers that the mobile sites are as small as possible, especially because our data plans here are extremely limited and expensive. I will raise a bug, because I am unable to get even the simplest Angular Dart app smaller that 650KB.

Comment: While looking for a current example of AngularDart code size I've found https://angulardart.org/demo/ – a bit huge at the moment. 1024 KB for the examples.dart.js

Comment: James, is 190KB "compiled and minifed" or "compiled, minified, and gzipped"? I'm seeing sizes of ~1.5MB (compiled + minified, not gzipped) for the AngularDart tutorials currently.

Answer (score 5):

What I have heard is a size of about 200KB+, never had a closer look myself. Dart targets bigger applications. It uses some boilerplate code of fixed size (this is generated no matter how big your custom code is) for emulating several of its generic functionality like classes. This doesn't pay off for small apps. The bigger the app gets the more this becomes an advantage.

They are still working for getting this better, but I guess you can expect only smaller improvements anymore.

How did you build your app to get this result?